# Various User roles in Rails(specifically version 5) without using gems like devise or cancancan

Tags: authentication, authorization, ruby-on-rails-5, user-roles

I am designing a fully-functional job boarding website on Rails 5 as a training project give by my company. I had no idea what Rails was until I read the Guide on Ruby on Rails and a book by Michael Hartl in Learn Enough Society.

I have a doubt regarding User model. I am not allowed to use any additional gems for Authentication or Authorization and there are three roles given to the user, that are, admin, recruiter and job-seeker.

I thought to use different models and controllers for all of them but it is not very helpful since there will further be controllers for Job application.This is also not beneficial since there are common attributes like name, email, password, contact etc which would be repeated as columns. Routing is also major concern for me.
I have another idea of having a User model with common attributes(and an attribute for role) and then having two other models for Recruiter and Job-seeker which would be inheriting from User model. I am unable to find relevant information.
Can I get any help from here? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow[SO]`, please be a bit more specific [when asking question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): What have you tried so far (with code example)? / What do you expect? / What error do you get?

Comment: I have not implemented any solution yet since I cannot find one. I don't have any specific code example. I am not allowed to use additional gems like devise or cancan in my application. I just need a suggestion to implement the situation of having various user roles in my application. All of them have different information to be stored so this process is to be done before just creating user model.

Comment: You can create `enum status: [:admin, :recruiter, :job-seeker]` and then add a field `user_role` in User model.

Comment: I found this solution doubtful. Every user roles have specific attributes and views. I don't understand how I would implement that if I go with this method. For example, The recruiter has official email id, company name, position, etc as its information, while the job-seeker has attributes like, qualification, area of interest, college-name, marks etc. I need to take these information during sign-up itself. How can I achieve that?